# A database migration/refactoring tool for RDF triple stores?

Tags: database, command-line, refactoring, etl

Is there a refactoring tool that can track changes in database migrations, similar to [Flyway](https://flywaydb.org/) or [Liquibase](https://www.liquibase.org/), *but for RDF triple stores*?

Triple stores are  similar to graph databases. They are used in the Semantic Web, as "SPARQL-databases".
Flyway and Liquibase increase reliability of database deployments by
versioning . Lightweight changes should be versioned, in the form of SPARQL-update commands)

A command line tool for Linux would be fine.